# adding multiple column in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have multiple column and row data , i want to place it in  table view  also i want make it scrollable vertically as well as horizontally . how to do this ? please help...

Comment: you cannot have columns by default in UITableView!!
You can create your custom view using a scroll view.

Comment: what exactly i have to do create custom cell view ? but its not scroll  horizontally. for scrolling what i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITableView is not meant to be used in a multi column way.

What you can do is to create custom UITableViewCells that look like two or more columns. But that will be just a workaround without the possibility to scroll horizontally.

The other possibility is to implement a UIScrollView. Add a View to the UIScrollView that is wider than the actuall iPhone screen. In this case the user will be able to scroll horizontally. In this case you will in deed not be able to use the predefined API-functionality of the UITableView and you have to render your table on your own.

Comment: Would be great if you could accept the answer (by clicking on the checkmark) if it was the info you were looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

My library, [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView), does what you want.
But it only supports vertical scrolling.

It is built with UITableView, in which UITableViewCell contains many cells inside.

You can try implement your own library, learn UIGridView's code, or use [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView).